# Using Tag model to create ManytoMany relationship

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I am trying to fetch data where the column value "tag" belongs to list from the table "UserBookmark".

```
  UserBookmark.objects.filter(tag__in = ['Java','Android'])
```

but this returns QuerySet[](null set) whereas I do have data matching this query in table

```
<QuerySet [<UserBookmark: 21 user12 http://careers.bankofamerica.com/ [u'Java']>,<UserBookmark: 22 user12 http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html [u'Data Science,Python']>,<UserBookmark: 23 user13 https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates [u'Android']>, <UserBookmark: 24 user14 https://github.com/sunnykrGupta/Bigquery-series [u'Python']>, <UserBookmark: 25 user14 https://github.com/ctfs/write-ups-2017 [u'Data Analytics']>]>
```

models.py

```
class UserBookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bookmark = models.URLField()
    tag = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%i %s %s %s'%(self.id,self.user,self.bookmark,self.tag)
```

i have modified my models.py

class UserBookmark(models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
bookmark = models.URLField()
tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag',blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '%i %s %s'%(self.id,self.user,self.bookmark)
```

class Tag(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

But when i run python manae.py migrate after python managepy makemigrations, I get this error:

ValueError: Cannot alter field bookmark.UserBookmark.tags into bookmark.UserBookmark.tags - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show your models ?

Comment: @ClémentDenoix yes i have added my models.py in the question.Please check

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not in your query, but in the way you are storing your data. You have a single CharField, and you seem to be populating it by simply converting a list to a string. So your records contain for example the literal string `"[u'Data Science,Python']"`.

If you want to store this kind of tag, you need to store the tags separately. One way to do this would be to set up a separate Tag model and use a many-to-many relationship. There are various third-party packages that do this for you - one example is [django-taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: I will look into this.Thanks :)

Comment: Also, if you use `postgreSQL` as the database, you could use the `ArrayField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Comment: @ClémentDenoix No i am using Sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Try to pluralize, maybe using `tags__in`

Comment: No that didn't work because field name is tag and not tags

Comment: can u post your models.py file

Comment: Yes i have added that in my question.